# loading saved bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i had saved a bitmap and i want to load it in runtime.

here is my codes:

> var saveDataTxt:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("File");
>
> var textName:String; var textClass:Class;
>
> textName = "Text0" + 1; 
>   textClass = getDefinitionByName(textName) as
>   Class;
>   var tx:BitmapData = new textClass();    txtP[1] = new
>   Bitmap(tx);
>
> saveDataTxt.data.txtArray[1]  = txtP[1];
>
> addChild(saveDataTxt.data.txtArray[n]);

but it gives me an error :

```
**TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@384c2b1 to flash.display.DisplayObject.**
```

whats the solution?

Comment: it seems like saveDataTxt.data.txtArray[n] isn't a displayobject, but just a regular object. What is stored in the sharedobject?

Comment: i'm trying to save a bitmap in sharedobject

Comment: You problem is likely that you need to register the class before loading back in.    See my answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667848/as3-for-ios-how-to-serialize-an-array-and-then-save-it/15668079#15668079

Comment: i just used above codes.  'saveDataTxt.data.txtArray[1] = txtP[1];'

Comment: Did you try doing:  `registerClassAlias("flash.display.Bitmap", Bitmap);`
    `registerClassAlias("flash.display.BitmapData", BitmapData);`

Comment: also, you don't define `n` in the code shown,  are you sure it's value is `1`?     Why wouldn't you just do `addChild(txtP[1]);`?   As it is, unless you're retrieving the bitmap somewhere else after the application is closed, there's no reason for you to be using sharedObject at all.

Comment: yeah, i wanna access to bitmaps after i close the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store a bitmap in a shared object, you would need to serialize it to a byte array first (see [Is it possible to store images in the SharedObject of Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486471/is-it-possible-to-store-images-in-the-sharedobject-of-flash))

What you can do, is just store your custom BitmapData subclass in the shared object (if you don't want to bother with byte arrays)

```
//you need to register every class/subclass in your shared object
registerClassAlias("flash.display.BitmapData", BitmapData);


var saveDataTxt:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("File");

var textName:String; var textClass:Class;

textName = "Text0" + 1; textClass = getDefinitionByName(textName) as Class;
registerClassAlias(textName,textClass); //need to register the custom class

var tx:BitmapData = new textClass(); txtP[1] = new Bitmap(tx);

saveDataTxt.data.txtArray[1] = tx; //just store the bitmap data

addChild(new Bitmap(saveDataTxt.data.txtArray[n] as BitmapData)); //you have to cast the object as bitmap data
```

Comment: thank you very much, actually i'm using for loop for that. i cast those objects as bitmap but now there is another error that says: TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()

Comment: i used trace and it shown me "object Object" without casting and "null" with casting as bitmap. i think i must save saveDataTxt.data.txtArray[1] = txtP[1] as bitmap. but how?

Comment: But have you put in the flash.net.registerClasAlias calls yet?

Comment: You may need to register your custom classes too then.  `Text01` or whatever they are called

Comment: i registered registerClassAlias("flash.display.textClass", textClass); and error is : TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter classObject must be non-null.at global/flash.net::registerClassAlias()

Comment: Just tried it myself.  Problem with bitmap is that the transform object needs parameters to be reconstructed.   What you can do, is forget the bitmap and just store the bitmapData.  updated my answer

Comment: You're probably registering the class before your populating that var. are you doing it like in my example?

Comment: i tried it and got me same error. my idea is assign to each bitmap a number and storing that numbers . but i dont know how can i do this.

Comment: could you do me a favor. that codes is simplified . can i send you original source and you look at it and find the solution. i think you find the problem faster. thank you so much.

Comment: If you edit your question to include a link to a source file I can take a look, though it may not be today.